# Is SciPy.optimize.minimize constrained optimization appropriate for this problem?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm building an agent-based SIR model and there is one part I am struggling with. Each period, susceptible agents have to solve the following problem:

[the optimization problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lPzh.png)

Here, Kit and Lambdait are Lagrangian multipliers. Now, I have solved the problem and brought it down to a system of five (nonlinear) equations with five unknowns.

[the system of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk8OB.png)

I have been looking around for Python packages to optimize these variables numerically (I have values for the other parameters). To me, SciPy.optimize.minimize seems appropriate, but I'm not quite sure whether this function is appropriate for the system of equations I just described or if it should be used for problems more similar to the original problem.
Also, if this method is appropriate, would you recommend COBYLA, SLSQP, or the trust-region method?

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Bobbus

Comment: This question might get better answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/, or https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/. Please consider moving your question there.

Comment: Okay I will, thanks